# Wrong request from Superset to MongoDB via Apach Drill

Tags: mongodb, request, nosql, apache-superset, apache-drill

I installed version 3.0.1 of Superset to display charts! I have a MongoDB database so that the superset can work with it, I installed Apache Drill 1.21.1
Everything works, but there is a problem with the Drill to Details functionality. When I click the "Drill To Detail" button I get this error: "Unexpected error: Error: The number that was passed in is not a number." If I look at Apache Drill's logs, a request comes:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm0fZ.png)
[Request in the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSlin.png)

and indeed, if I check this request in the SQL Lab tab, it returns null
[Wrong request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81NrB.png)
I deleted (*) from request and
[Correct request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2ouc.png)
it works well, it retunrs 919176

If I clicl the "View as table" it works well.

I tried to register custom queries, but it didn’t help.
If anyone has encountered something similar and somehow solved it, please let me know! I've been trying to solve this problem for 2-3 weeks now